# How to resolve this NullPointerException being thrown from HibernateTemplate's find(String query) method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

How do I resolve this NullPointerException ?
A little background , I am developing a Spring based Project and using HibernateTemlate in DAO layer to do all database related operations.

here is the snippet of code which i have extracted out of my test class which is throwing NullPointerException.

```
   try {
                   List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) ht.find("select uomId,uomModel from in.nit.model.Uom");
                   System.out.println(list);
               }catch(NullPointerException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

And this is the stacktrace of the exception on the console.

````
```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at in.nit.dao.impl.UomDaoImplTest.test(UomDaoImplTest.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Here is my model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="uomtab")
public class Uom {

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="umid") private Integer uomId;
    @Column(name="utype") private String uomType;
    @Column(name="umodel") private String uomModel;
    @Column(name="udesc") private String uomDesc;

    public Uom() {
        super();
    }

    public Uom(Integer uomId) {
        this.uomId = uomId;
    }

    public Integer getUomId() {
        return uomId;
    }
    public void setUomId(Integer uomId) {
        this.uomId = uomId;
    }
    public String getUomType() {
        return uomType;
    }
    public void setUomType(String uomType) {
        this.uomType = uomType;
    }
    public String getUomModel() {
        return uomModel;
    }
    public void setUomModel(String uomModel) {
        this.uomModel = uomModel;
    }
    public String getUomDesc() {
        return uomDesc;
    }
    public void setUomDesc(String uomDesc) {
        this.uomDesc = uomDesc;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Uom [uomId=" + uomId + ", uomType=" + uomType + ", uomModel=" + uomModel + ", 
      uomDesc=" + uomDesc + "]";
    }
}

```
````

Also even though the find(String Query) method is deprecated,I have extensively used it in other dao classes of my project which works smooth and fine.

What could be the possible reasons for this exception blowing up my code?

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't catch that NullPointerException
2. What is line 28 in your code?
3. Did you try and debug the line? If it is the ht.find line, the only thing that makes sense is that your HibernateTemplate is null and has not been set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

your error is in class "UomDaoImplTest". That has no relation with Hibernate Template.
can you post your test class.